# Select matched records in two ordered sets joined together

Tags: sql, sql-server

Let's assume a table named Cities has three columns. `ID`, `City` and `Country` and it contains thousands of city names from entire world. I am trying to write a SQL query to accomplish the below. If a user from Brazil searches for cities with names starting with "sal", I want the records to be sorted in such a way that all matching cities in Brazil are top ordered alphabetically (e.g. Salvador) and then the matching cities from the rest of the world (e.g. Salamina) ordered alphabetically.

I tried something like this but it is a syntax error if I remove the commented out part:

```sql
SELECT TOP 10 * FROM Cities WHERE City LIKE 'sal%' AND Country = 'Brazil' ORDER BY Country, City

UNION

SELECT TOP 10 * FROM Cities WHERE City LIKE 'sal%' AND Country <> 'Brazil' ORDER BY City
```

This is for SQL Server (through Entity Framework if that helps)

Comment: Union can only have one sort, you can't sort the unioned parts by themselves. The sort can be rewritten as `order by case when country ='Brasil' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, City`. This prioritises country match. So remove the union and just match on city